# How to produce Unicode characters with Matlab LaTex interpreter

Tags: matlab, unicode, utf-8, latex, tex

I have the following line of code

```
ylabel('Średnia wartość parametru $f_{max}$','Interpreter','latex');
```

and would like to use it as a label for my plot. Unfortunately what I actually get is:

```
Warning: Unable to interpret LaTeX string
```

If I remove Unicode characters like so:

```
ylabel('Srednia wartosc parametru $f_{max}$','Interpreter','latex');
```

it works with no problem.

So how could I make Matlab print those unfortunate characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LaTeX representations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Escaped_codes) for those characters: `\'S`, `\'s`, etc. And don't forget to duplicate quote signs within the string:

```
ylabel('\''Srednia warto\''s\''c parametru $f_{max}$','Interpreter','latex')
```